# Pip invalid command egg_info

Tags: python, pip, egg

I recently upgraded pip and it broke things.

I tried running this:

```
    sudo pip install -U ipython pyzmq
    Requirement already up-to-date: ipython in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    Downloading/unpacking pyzmq
      Downloading pyzmq-14.5.0.tar.gz (997kB): 997kB downloaded
      Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pyzmq/setup.py) egg_info for package pyzmq
        usage info....


    error: invalid command 'egg_info'

    ----------------------------------------
    Cleaning up...
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pyzmq
    Storing debug log for failure in /Users/asselinpaul/.pip/pip.log
    ➜  ~  pip show setuptools
    ---
    Name: setuptools
    Version: 15.0
    Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-15.0-py2.7.egg
    Requires:
```

More info:

```
    ➜  ~  which python
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
    ➜  ~  which pip
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

Curiously, setuptools is not found but installed.

```
    ➜  ~  which setuptools
          setuptools not found

    ➜  ~  sudo pip install -U setuptools
          Password:
          Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-15.0-py2.7.egg
          Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like you (also on a Mac). I deleted (`rm -r`) all the files and folders from `~/env-backend/backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which had setuptools in it (`ls | grep setup`).

Then I installed setuptools using the curl instructions from [python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-including-mac-os-x-curl) (`> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python`) and it worked fine for me thereafter.